# Socket won't connect to Endpoint

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

```
var socket = new Socket("localhost:4000")
socket.connect()
```

Returns `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

But I do have the socket on the `/ws` endpoint, right?

```
defmodule Sapphire.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :sapphire

  socket "/ws", Sapphire.MomentSocket

  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/", from: :sapphire, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)

  if code_reloading? do
    socket "/phoenix/live_reload/socket", Phoenix.LiveReloader.Socket
    plug Phoenix.LiveReloader
    plug Phoenix.CodeReloader
  end

  plug Plug.RequestId
  plug Plug.Logger

  plug Plug.Parsers,
    parsers: [:urlencoded, :multipart, :json],
    pass: ["*/*"],
    json_decoder: Poison

  plug Plug.MethodOverride
  plug Plug.Head

  plug Plug.Session,
    store: :cookie,
    key: "_sapphire_key",
    signing_salt: "hW1bFEcR"

  plug Sapphire.Router

end
```

It should be able to connect to that endpoint, but for some reason it can't reach it at all.

`[info] Running Sapphire.Endpoint with Cowboy on http://localhost:4000`

Comment: Because you are accessing `ws://localhost:4000/ws`, i have a hunch you are using an old Phoenix client with a recent Phoenix application. Make sure you are using Phoenix 1.0.2 and that you have the latest copy of Phoenix.js.

Comment: @JoséValim Hmm, I've ported https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/web/static/js/phoenix.js to coffeescript in which the front-end is being served on a different server. The client autoadds the `/ws`, so I have `socket "/ws", Sapphire.MomentSocket` should that not be available on the `/ws` path? Even changing both to `/socket` returns the same 404. I'm interested in how that socket endpoint gets exposed

Comment: The URL is socket_path + transport_name. So it should be /socket/websockets or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@JoséValim found the solution.

I was porting the phoenix.js library to coffeescript and missed the fact that the suffix of the path should be whatever the transport layer is. In this case, it needed `/websocket` at the end in the implementation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure -- I'm a noob, and I'm probably screwing something up, but this is how I got back on track.

```
rm -rf deps/phoenix
```

This will clear out your present version of phoenix (which includes phoenix.js)

```
mix do deps.get
```

This pulls down phoenix again.

Hopefully this is enough to get you going again at this point -- but if you screwed up a migration like me, and you're on mac/linux, do a:

```
find . -name phoenix.js
```

Voila, there is the phoenix.js fixed by Jose.  I was lazy and just copied over that phoenix.js to get things going for the time being.