# Phoenix: Trying to connect to Channel but getting a not Route found for GET /websocket error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to hook up an Angular 2 frontend to a Phoenix app using Channels (Websockets). They are completely seperate and run on different ports on localhost (phoenix on 4000, angular 2 on 5555). Strangely I'm getting a `(Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for GET /websocket (MyApp.Router)` error on the backend. And a code 1006 error on the frontend:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/websocket?vsn=1.0.0' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`.

`// endpoint.ex`

```
defmodule MyApp.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :my_app

  # socket "/socket", MyApp.UserSocket
  socket "/websocket", MyApp.PostSocket

  # Serve at "/" the static files from "priv/static" directory.
  #
  # You should set gzip to true if you are running phoenix.digest
  # when deploying your static files in production.
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/", from: :my_app, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)

  # Code reloading can be explicitly enabled under the
  # :code_reloader configuration of your endpoint.
  if code_reloading? do
    socket "/phoenix/live_reload/socket", Phoenix.LiveReloader.Socket
    plug Phoenix.LiveReloader
    plug Phoenix.CodeReloader
  end

  plug Plug.RequestId
  plug Plug.Logger

  plug Plug.Parsers,
    parsers: [:urlencoded, :multipart, :json],
    pass: ["*/*"],
    json_decoder: Poison

  plug Plug.MethodOverride
  plug Plug.Head

  plug Plug.Session,
    store: :cookie,
    key: "_my_app_key",
    signing_salt: "qCSHk+9O"

    plug CORSPlug, [
      origin: "http://localhost:5555",
      headers: ["X-Auth-Token" | CORSPlug.defaults[:headers]]
    ]

  plug MyApp.Router
end
```

`PostSocket`:

```
defmodule MyApp.PostSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket

  ## Channels
  channel "post:*", MyApp.PostChannel

  ## Transports
  transport :websocket, Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket
  transport :longpoll, Phoenix.Transports.LongPoll


  def connect(_params, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end

  def id(_socket), do: nil
end
```

On the frontend, using the phoenix js client:

```
var socket = new Socket("ws://localhost:4000", {
  logger: ((kind, msg, data) => { console.log(`${kind}: ${msg}`, data) }),
  transport: WebSocket
});
socket.connect();
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665406/socket-wont-connect-to-endpoint) had an answer by José Valim that pointed me in the right direction.

> the suffix of the path should be whatever the transport layer is. In
>   this case, it needed /websocket at the end in the implementation.

So in my endpoint I changed the route from `/websocket` to `/socket` to prevent confusion:

```
defmodule TropeApi.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :trope_api

  socket "/socket", TropeApi.PostSocket

  # ...

end
```

And then changed the js implementation to reflect that. I also added the transport parameter to the options (just to mention in case this has anything to do with it, which I don't think).

```
var socket = new Socket("ws://localhost:4000/socket", {
  logger: ((kind, msg, data) => { console.log(`${kind}: ${msg}`, data) }),
  transport: WebSocket
});
socket.connect();
```

The connection now goes to `ws://localhost:4000/socket/websocket`. The last part (`websocket`) let to some confusion for me but was cleared up now.

Comment: Thanks for this question/answer, it helped me to solve the url issue as well. For those who stumble upon here, the client shall try to connect to ws://localhost:4000/socket/websocket. In that case Phoenix establishes a websocket connection.