# phoenix.js: WebSocket connection to ws://localhost:4000/socket failed

Tags: javascript, sockets, reactjs, elixir, phoenix-framework

I get this error in the Chrome console on my Phoenix/React app—but, strangely, **not** in incognito mode. Everything is pointed to the same `/socket` endpoint.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/socket/websocket?token=blah&vsn=1.0.0' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

[Various sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324142/1342734) say it's about the transport layer, which makes a bit of sense since this is what's highlighted in the console where the error is:

```
this.conn = new this.transport(this.endPointURL());
```

The React app finds the endpoint like so:

```
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:4000/api';
const WEBSOCKET_URL = API_URL.replace(/(https|http)/, 'ws').replace('/api', '');

function connectToSocket(dispatch) {
  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
  const socket = new Socket(`${WEBSOCKET_URL}/socket`, {
    params: { token },
  });
  socket.connect();
  dispatch({ type: 'SOCKET_CONNECTED', socket });
}
```

**NB:** Amending that line to `const socket = new Socket('${WEBSOCKET_URL}/socket/websocket'` just makes the error read `.../socket/websocket/websocket?...`.

The `endpoint.ex` is pretty standard:

```
socket "/socket", App.UserSocket
```

None of this points to why the app would work in incognito and load all these errors otherwise, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll post how I fixed this because it might help someone else, although I'm not really certain why it's the case. Just change `localhost` in both the front and the back to the IP address:

In `config.ex`:

```
config :app, App.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "127.0.0.1"]...
```

In your front end:

```
const API_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/api';
```